# I have a JSON response like this, and I'm having trouble access the value for some reason

Tags: javascript, ajax, arrays, json

JSON response:

```
{ "success" : "false" }
```

Way I thought you access the data:

```
if (data.success[0] == "false") {
    alert("Login Successful");
}
else {
    alert("Login Failed");
}
```

It's going to the else condition.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `data.success == 'false'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are supposed to access an object not an array

```
if (data.success === false)
```

Your response should be

```
{ "success" : false }
```

otherwise you will need to compare to a string:

```
if (data.success === "false")
```

Answer (score 0):

`data.success` is a string and not an array, so you do not need the `[0]`.

For your current JSON response, the `if` statement should read:

```
if(data.success === 'false') {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like these guys said the object you are trying to access is not an **array** so you would not need the **[0]**

what this is doing is returning the letter at the **index** of [0] so if you were to log/alert `data.success[0]` you would get *" F "* because it is the first letter in the string that you are returning.

a more common practice would be to return a Boolean of `false`

`{ "success" : false }`
-----------------------^--------^
notice no " " marks

and then again no  " " marks

-----------------------------------v-------v

```
if (data.success === false) {
  alert("Login Successful");
}
else {
  alert("Login Failed");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

"false" is a string, not a boolean. You should compare data.success to "false"

```
if(data.success=="false") {
```

Comment: dont use the [0] success is not an array it is a string